# Convert JavaScript string format into another

Tags: javascript, string

I have a mobile no like (408) 931-4377 and need to create a format like (000) 000-0000 for validating other mobile nos

Please suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you please explain more? so we can understand what you exactly need.

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh Sorry, I updated the question again now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.replace` in javascript

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const number = "(408) 931-4377";
console.log(number.replace(/[0-9]/g, "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions for this Validation.

````
const number = "(408) 931-4377";
const mobilecheck = RegEx(/^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/);

if(mobilecheck.test(number)){
// do something
}
else{
// do something
}```
````

Comment: `/.../` already created a RegExp object. No need to also pass it to the RegExp (not `ReEx` by the way) constructor.